# .NET page works in Firefox but not in IE

Tags: .net, internet-explorer, firefox

I have weird problem and don't know how to solve it.

I have webpage that basically on server side does something like this in Page_Load event:

```
if (Page.User.IsInRole("Admin"))
{
    ButtonEdit.Visible = true;
}
```

Basically, if user is an Admin, I will show Edit button (which is otherwise hidden). This concept works everywhere within web application except on one single page. I've put some code breaks and realized that on this page Page.User.IsInRole("Admin") always returns false.

For things to be more confusing, everything works fine in Firefox. Code on problematic page performs as expected.

So, to sumarize, user, an admin, that is experiencing this problem (only one so far) sees following:

- Test1 webserver: **Edit button shows in IE and Firefox**
- Test2 webserver: **Edit button shows in IE and Firefox**
- Production webserver: **No Edit Button in IE, but there is Edit button in Firefox**

The only thing I noticed is that CSS sometime breaks on the same page (not too often, sort of hard to recreate), then html elements look like no css styles were applied. I suspect that there is missing closing tag or quote or something which causes IE to crash.
But not sure how to locate culprit. There are no javascript or any other errors on the page. The page code is pretty big and going line by line is option I am trying to avoid.

Is there a way to validate HTML in Visual Studio 2010, and somehow make sure that all tags are properly written?

Thanks for any suggestion.

Thanks

Comment: Is production running a load balancer?

Answer (score 0):

What you say is strange to me too.

I suggest you first press CTRL+K, CTRL+D on your file to reformat all the indents and look good. if it worked fine, then probably your HTML is okay.

if not, try to eliminate some parts of your code and render again to find the problem. Another thing that might help is that when you click on a starting of a tag of your document, both starting and ending will become bold. If VS fails to bold an ending tag, this could be a good start for you.

And there is one known error I know which took me some time once:

an script tag cannot be closed immediately. i.e.

```
<script type="text/javascript" scr="someurl" />
```

is wrong and makes lots of browsers to fail rendering.

it should be replaced with:

```
<script type="text/javascript" scr="someurl" ></script>
```

Comment: No. None of that. I have looked line by line. I managed to fix CSS issues on IE and problem with Page.User.IsInRole("Admin") returning always false stayed. I think that there is something wrong with the server. Missing some patch or something. Don't know how else to describe this IE nonsense. User is using IE7. I upgraded her to IE8. Still the same.